# Latex long table reduce the column size ? and add new number in each table?

Tags: numbering, longtable

How I can reduce the column size of the first column and new index numbering in each table ?

**Package I am using**

```
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\usepackage{longtable}

Table code
%--------------------------------------------
\begin{center} \begin{longtable}  {|p{0.2mm}|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|}
\endfirsthead \endhead
\multicolumn{1}{r}{{Continued on Next Page}}
\endfoot\endlastfoot \hline
%-------------------------------------------
& User  &   System \\   \hline
\rownumber & Test & Test \\ \hline
\rownumber & & Test \\  \hline
%-------------------------------------------
\caption{Test} \end{longtable} \label{tab:foo_1} \end{center}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciate ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined a new counter `magicrownumbers` but you are not using it.

Probably you wanted to define `\rownumber` as

```
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
```

And to reduce the size of the first column, the `\multicolumn` you have used should span 3 columns.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\begin{document}
Table code
%--------------------------------------------
\begin{longtable}{|p{5mm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\endfirsthead \endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on Next Page}}
\endfoot\endlastfoot 
%-------------------------------------------
& User  &   System \\   \hline
\rownumber & Test & Test \\ \hline
\rownumber & & Test \\  \hline
%-------------------------------------------
\caption{Test}\label{tab:foo_1}
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

BTW: inserting a `longtable` in a `center` environment does nothing but adding unwanted spacing. Unless differently specified, a `longtable` is centered in the page by default.

---

### EDIT

If you have to use your numbering algorithm in other tables and you want the line counter to restart at each table, define the new counter as

```
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}[table]
```

instead of simply

```
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
```

In this way `magicrownumbers` is reset at the beginning of each new table.

Comment: How do I add new index number in each table ? Could you please add this also ? Thanks.

Comment: @Trickster See the edit.

Comment: @Trickster You're welcome. :-)

Comment: Where do you put the `\newcounter{magicrownumbers}[table]` line, please?